# HTML 5 navigation menu

Tags: html, css, nav

This is my HTML5 for nav bar. However, the submenu will not hide and the menu will not display horizontally. Home, American and Foreign and the topmenu options and speed,usability and price are submeny. However Foriegn is displaying below and not next to American. Thank you in advance.

```
<nav>
  <ul class="topmenu">
  <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="american.html">American</a></li>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li> <a href="index.html">Speed</a></li>
    <li> <a href="index.html">Price</a></li>
    <li> <a href="index.html">Usability</a></li>
    </ul>
  <li><a href="foreign.html">Foreign</a></li>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li> <a href="index.html">Speed</a></li>
    <li> <a href="index.html">Price</a></li>
    <li> <a href="index.html">Usability</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00baff;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.topmenu li{
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    color: white;
}
.topmenu li a{
    padding: 5px;
}
.topmenu a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.topmenu a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.topmenu a:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.topmenu li .submenu li{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.topmenu li:hover .submenu li{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKwKt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

CSS:

```
nav{
position: relative;
background-color: #00baff;
width: 50%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
/* This is your main UL resize to fit */
.topmenu{
width: 100%;    
height: 150px;
}
/* I used > li to target all elements of .topmenu */
.topmenu > li{
font-size: 20px;
margin-right: 10px;
color: white;
list-style:none;
display:inline;
float: left;
}
.topmenu > li a{
padding: 5px;
}
.topmenu a:link{
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
}
.topmenu a:visited{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
.topmenu a:hover{
background-color: #ffffff;
}


/* new code 
 What this does is it targets all child UL elements on li:hover
  if they have them they will become VISIBLE if not nothing happens */
.topmenu > li:hover >ul{
visibility:visible;
}

/* your two sub menus set to hidden */
.american-submenu{
visibility:hidden;
}
.foreign-submenu{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul class="topmenu">
<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="american.html">American</a>
<ul class="american-submenu">
        <li> <a href="index.html">Speed</a></li>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Price</a></li>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Usability</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="foreign.html">Foreign</a>
 <ul class="foreign-submenu">
            <li> <a href="index.html">Speed</a></li>
            <li> <a href="index.html">Price</a></li>
            <li> <a href="index.html">Usability</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help LJ, unfortunetly, it had no change

Comment: Is there a way you can post a screenshot? And also when you say it doesn't go horizontal r u talking about submenu or main menu or both?

Comment: okay, here is a link to an interactive html and css editing page.    http://jsfiddle.net/GKwKt/

Comment: okay, i got most of it working, however when you hover your mouse over the menus, they fly up!  http://jsfiddle.net/GKwKt/3/

Comment: I did whole thing for you all you need to do is re size the main UL I left comments

Comment: Can you link me to what you did? I can't see it anywhere! thanks

Comment: The code above I didn't use jsfiddle I wrote it on my computer and tested it if you copy top code it will work 100% all you need to do is play with size that you need and colors that you want.. I left comments inside the CSS part so you can see what I did and why.. It can help you learn. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Alright thanks! i THink this is as close as it will get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HMTL**

```
<nav>
  <ul class="topmenu">
  <li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="american.html">American</a>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Speed</a></li>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Price</a></li>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Usability</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
  <li><a href="foreign.html">Foreign</a>
        <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Speed</a></li>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Price</a></li>
    <li> <a href="index.html">Usability</a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
      nav{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #00baff;
    width:100%;
    }
.topmenu ul {
     list-style:none;
}
.topmenu li {
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
      list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00baff;
    color: white;
     text-align:center;
    padding:5px;

}
.topmenu li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.topmenu li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    background-color: #00baff;
    color:white;
     height:auto; 
      width:8em;
}
.topmenu li ul li{
    clear:both;
border-style:none;}

.topmenu li a{
    padding: 5px;
}
.topmenu a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.topmenu a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.topmenu a:hover{
    background-color:white ;
    color:#00baff;
}
```

Fiddle [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf7HS/33/)

Comment: Can you check the fiddle demo and say is that okay??

Comment: Well not really, for one, the alignment went from the center (intended) to the left. The background color was initially blue, and the menus have too much space in between. I am now trying to get the menu to be center of page, with no luck so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GKwKt/3/ This is what i wanted it to look like, but in that one, the submenu will not work correctly.

Comment: Perfect! Just one more favor! for submenu, when you hover, how can i make the border stretch across the whole submenu block?

Comment: If it works can you please mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful for someone in the future. and i will make the necessary changes too.

Comment: Well it is a close answer, not the perfect answer.